# How to match up the segmented image labels with the 'ground truth' labels from berkeley dataset

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

My problem is how can a compare the segmented image labels by my algorithm with the ground truth labels of the Berkeley segmentation dataset:

for example, my segmented image has this labels:

[1 1 1 2 2 2 2 4 4 4]

and the ground truth labels are:

[4 4 4 2 2 2 2  1 1 1]

so how can I match the result of my segmentation algorithm with the ground truth labels to compute after, the precision and the recall, because when I want to compute the presion and the recall of my results segmentation with the ground truth, they display the value (NaN in Matlab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the standard procedure consists on thresholding the segmentation regions found (Both ground truth and your result), then apply a morphological reconstruction such that all boundaries are of same width and then compare them.

This is implemented on this fast evaluation benchmark: http://157.253.63.7/BSDS500FastBench.tar.gz. This receives as input a cell array that contains your segmentation results and compares them with the human annotated masks. It also plots and generates a Precision-Recall curve.

I hope this may help you.

Comment: Dear @Edgar thank you for your response, I'm still searching in the folder that you gave me, the name of the function which can do that...

Comment: I forgot completely to tell you, that for each image, you must save a mat file named with the image id, this file contains the cell array I told you earlier

Comment: Then you can use allBench_fast(imgDir, gtDir, inDir, outDir, nthresh);

Comment: @EdgarAndrésMargffoyTuay unable to download the allBench_fast function. please provide another link. thanks.